# SQL query with IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a page, thats like facebook feed page.
So, my query now look like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM event 
        WHERE id_user IN (
              SELECT a.id_user_stalkers 
              FROM stalkers a 
              WHERE a.id_user = ".$id_profile.")  
        ORDER by date DESC 
        LIMIT 0, 10";
```

stalkers - friends

Table Stalkers:

```
id  id_user  id_user_friend
```

I need to append to that IN clause my personal ID, so my qyery returns my events and my friends event.

Can anybody help me ?

What I have tried

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
         FROM event 
         WHERE id_user IN (
               SELECT a.id_user_stalkers 
               FROM stalkers a  
               WHERE a.id_user = ".$id_profile.") 
        OR id_user = ".$id_profile."  
        ORDER by date DESC 
        LIMIT 0, 10";
```

Comment: What happens when you run the last query?

Comment: is there an error or it doesn't return the desired output?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, could you try explaining your problem again.

Comment: and also, you should look into prepared statements, rather than building up the sql the way you do - but that's another issue... ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! I have fixed it. It was not broken at all.

Answer (score 1):

it looks something wrong in your sql and your table

1-in your table you have `id_user_friend` and in your sql you are making `id_user_stalkers`.

2- i dont know if you have date in your first table , or you mean `NOW()` .? since u didnt share the first table.

try this

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM event e WHERE id_user 
           IN (SELECT a.id_user_friend FROM stalkers a  
           WHERE a.id_user = ".$id_profile.")
            OR e.id_user = ".$id_user." 
          ORDER by e.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

What is $id_user ?  The original query only has one variable.  I don't see why you need another.  In other words, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM event e
WHERE id_user IN (SELECT a.id_user_friend
                  FROM stalkers a  
                  WHERE a.id_user = ".$id_profile."
                 ) OR
     e.id_user = ".$id_profile." 
ORDER by e.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```